# How to find duplicates in a Python list of lists which elements are numpy.ndarray of shape (9, 103)

Tags: python, numpy

I got a list (I call chunks) with `len(chunks)=195` and `len(chunks[0]) = 32`. The elements inside `chunks[0]` are of type `numpy.ndarray` and shape (9,103).

```
type(chunks[0][0])   
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>   
type(chunks[0][0][0])  
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>  
type(chunks[0][0][0][0])  
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

I'm trying to find if there are duplicates in `chunks[0]`. The most appropriate way I thought of was `len(chunks[0]) != set(chunks[0])` but that throws an error: 'TypeError: unhashable type'.

Is there another workable way to investigate whether elements inside the `chunks[0]` are equal and if so to eliminate the duplicates from the list? Could transforming them to tensors be advisable to check for duplicates in a fast way?

Comment: Can you clarify what duplicates are in your use case? Is it `chunks[i] == chunks[j]` means they are duplicates, or is it at a lower lever?

Comment: @joanis: the elements in chunks[0]. So if 1 or more out of the 32 in that chunk are equal or not. Then later on repeat the same for the other 195 chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### The problem

Hashables data types, i.e., those that can be used as elements in sets or keys in dicts, have to be immutable. That's because you have to get the same hash value each time you try to look for it, but if you could modify it, the hash value would change. For example, lists and arrays can be changed and are therefore not hashable, but tuples are immutable so they are hashable.

##### One possible solution

You can create a tuple containing the values from your list or array or list of arrays, and use that in your set.

##### Sample code

You could use functions like these to solve your problem:

```
def 2d_array_to_tuples(a):
    return tuple(tuple(row) for row in a)

def list_of_2d_arrays_to_tuples(a_list):
    return tuple(2d_array_to_typles(a) for a in a_list)
```

These two functions return "2D" and "3D" tuples, which are hashable. You can insert their return values into sets.

And then this could work to detect if two chunks contain the same 32 arrays in the same order:

```
len(chunks) != len(set(list_of_2d_arrays_to_tuples(chunk) for chunk in chunks))
```

Or if you want to look for duplicate arrays within `chunks[0]`:

```
len(chunks[0]) != len(set(2d_array_to_tuples(a) for a in chunks[0]))
```

##### Eliminating the duplicates

If you want to eliminate the duplicates in the list, I would unroll those code a bit. Let `chunk = chunks[0]` and say you want `uniq_chunk` to have the arrays from `chunk` without the duplicates. This code should do the trick:

```
found = set()
uniq_chunk = []
for a in chunk:
    as_tuple = 2d_array_to_tuples(a)
    if as_tuple not in found:
        found.add(as_tuple)
        uniq_chunk.append(a)
```

You can adjust this approach to the exact thing you're trying to deduplicate.

Comment: thank you, your suggested solution helped with the unhashable issue.